# Homebrew nodejs issue

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I'd had nodejs installed on my laptop using macOS installer. Some time later I've decided to update its version and install via HomeBrew. I've tracked such folders "node", "node_modules" in `/usr/`. Then I deleted "node" execution file.

After that I decided that laptop is ready for HomeBrew installation and ran `brew install node`. The installation was successfully completed without any warning. However, I'm not able to execute such command as `node -v` or `npm -v`. It says `-bash: node: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing permissions on "/usr/local/share/doc/node/" for "wheel" to "write/read" and running command
`brew link --overwrite node`